# Stopping a function, Arrays, and Integer Check

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

So I made code for creating 5 ships in a battleship game.  I succesfully made some code that layed out all the players ships.  It had no bugs.  I had the player write out the cords for where he wanted to position his ship.  It would then write in the ship position to the corresponding part in a two dimensional array which was the game map..  Of course the cords had to be integers or it would crash and burn.

So I then made something to check if the coordinate was a integer before doing anything else.  If it wasn't it would restart the function making so that the rest of the function wouldn't run.  If you write in the numbers correctly there are no problems.  The problem is that if you don't write in a number the function does restart but the function or some part of it must still be running because a ship gets written to the array for no reason.  The cords haven't even been specified for it so I have no clue how this can be possible.

Here is the code I made for checking if its an integer and restarting the function.

```
userYTest = parseInt(prompt("Horizontal Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship"));
userXTest = parseInt(prompt("Vertical Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship"));

        if(userXTest % 1 === 0 && userYTest % 1 === 0) {
            userY = userYTest-1;
            userX = userXTest-1;
            direction = prompt("Now choose the direction you want the rest of your ship to face.  You may   use the words left, right up, or down.").toLowerCase(); 
        }
        else{
            window.alert("You must enter a number between one and ten for the two coordinates.");
            ship();
//ship is the name of the function
        }
```

Here is all the code.

```
//These are all the different game boards you need to keep track of. Two possible values in each position 1 or 0
var user = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
var cpu = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
var userGuessed = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
var userHit = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
var cpuGuessed = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
var cpuHit = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

var clearBoard = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

// These are just used to set left the game board.
// I counted 10 by 10 - it should be 10 by 10
var userY = 0;
var userX = 0;
var cpuX = 0;
var cpuY = 0;
var cpuDir = 0;
var cpuWork = false;
var direction = "";
var isThere = false;
var i=0;
var userXTest;
var userYTest;

// In battleship, there is 1x5 length ship, 1x4 length ship, 2 1x3 length ship, and 1x2 length ship. down now it checks how many units are covered to see if you have all the ships. Later we need to add so they ships are the down shape


//User will add their ships here one by one.  If you can think of a better have a go at it!

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if (i===0){
        window.alert("We will be placing your 1 by 5 length ship.  Take note that you are playing on a 10 by 10 board.");
        ship();
    }
    if (i===1){
        window.alert("We will be placing your 1 by 4 length ship.  Take note that you are playing on a 10 by 10 board.");
        ship();
    }
    if (i===2){
        window.alert("We will be placing your two 1 by 3 length ships.  Take note that you are playing on a 10 by 10 board.");
        ship();
        ship();
    }
    if (i===3){
        window.alert("We will be placing your 1 by 2 length ship.  Take note that you are playing on a 10 by 10 board.");
        ship();
    }
    function ship(){
        userYTest = parseInt(prompt("Horizontal Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship"));
        userXTest = parseInt(prompt("Vertical Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship"));

        if(userXTest % 1 === 0 && userYTest % 1 === 0) {
            userY = userYTest-1;
            userX = userXTest-1;
            direction = prompt("Now choose the direction you want the rest of your ship to face.  You may   use the words left, right up, or down.").toLowerCase(); 
        }
        else{
            window.alert("You must enter a number between one and ten for the two coordinates.");
            ship();
        }
        //Making sure the ship will fit and nothing is already there!
        if ((userY+4-i)>9 && direction=== "down"){
         window.alert("You are too close to the down edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
         ship();
        }
        else if ((userY-4-i)<0 && direction=== "up"){
         window.alert("You are too close to the up edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
         ship();
        }
        else if ((userX+4-i)>9 && direction=== "right"){
         window.alert("You are too close to the bottom edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
         ship();
        }
        else if ((userX-4-i)<0 && direction=== "left"){
         window.alert("You are too close to the top edge of the board to do that. Restarting...");
         ship();
        }
        else if (user[userY][userX] === 1) {
            window.alert("Coordinate already used. Please try again");
            ship();
        } 

        else if (user[userY][userX] === null || user[userY][userX] === ""){
            window.alert("That coordinate isn't on the board. Restarting...");
            ship();
        }

        else if(direction ==="left" || direction ==="right" || direction ==="up" || direction ==="down") {
            for(var a=1; a<5-i; a++){

                if(direction=== "down"){
                    if(user[userY+a][userX] === 1){
                        window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                        isThere=true;
                    }
                }
                if(direction=== "up"){
                    if(user[userY-a][userX] === 1){
                        window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                        isThere=true;
                    }
                }
                if(direction=== "right"){
                    if(user[userY][userX+a] === 1 ){
                        window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                        isThere=true;
                    }
                }
                if(direction=== "left"){
                    if(user[userY][userX-a] === 1){
                        window.alert("Can't place your ship in that direction, another ship is in your way.");
                        isThere=true;
                    }
                }
                if(isThere===true){
                    isThere = false;
                    ship(); 
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    user[userY][userX] = 1;
                }
            }

        }
        else{
            window.alert("Sorry but you didn't type in the direction you wanted your ship to go correctly. Restarting...");
            ship();
        }


        // Building Ship 1x5
        for(var b=1; b<5-i; b++){

            if (direction==="left"){
                user[userY][userX-b] =1;
            }
            else if (direction==="right"){
                user[userY][userX+b] =1;
            }
            else if (direction==="up"){
                user[userY-b][userX] =1;
            }
            else if (direction==="down"){
                user[userY+b][userX] =1;
            }
        }
}

}

console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand that calling a function within itself does not stop running the original function. Try [this (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/qARDh/2/) to see how it works:

```
var i = 0;
function askDogsName() {
    var dogsName = prompt("What is the dog's name?");
    if (dogsName != "Rover") {
        askDogsName();
    }
    i++;
    document.body.innerHTML += "i = " + i
        + "; dog's name: " + dogsName + '<br />';
}
askDogsName();
```

After the new recursion of the function has completed, the original one simply carries on where it left off; it does not 'restart'. So this is not a good way of responding to user input that is not valid, especially because you are using global variables. Each recursion of the function can alter those variables in a way that can become difficult to predict, before returning control to its 'parent' (the recursion of the function that called it).

What you can do instead is to use return values to check whether the correct input has been given or not:

```
function ship() {
     var c;
     while (!c) {
         c = getValidCoords();
     }
     x = c[0];
     y = c[1];
     // then make the ship at x, y
 }
 function getValidCoords() {
     y = parseInt(prompt("Horizontal Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship"));
     x = parseInt(prompt("Vertical Coordinate position for the first unit of a ship"));
     // conduct various tests on x and y
     if (testsFail) {
         return false;
     }
     return [x, y];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake, I thought that if I called the function over again it would start it over.  All it actually did was call it inside that if statement and then continue resulting in it going twice when I thought it only went once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't recurse when its wrong. Try something like this:

```
var done;
while (!done) {
    if(userXTest % 1 === 0 && userYTest % 1 === 0) {
        userY = userYTest-1;
        userX = userXTest-1;
        direction = prompt("Now choose the direction you want the rest of your ship to face.  You may   use the words left, right up, or down.").toLowerCase(); 

        ... All the other tests that are after the else part ...

        else { // if its a good answer
            done = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        window.alert("You must enter a number between one and ten for the two coordinates.");
    }

}
```

You will want some way they can say they want to quit too.

Comment: I was able to recurse for every other condition though. What was the difference between that and this?

Comment: @Zachooz Prior to starting the other conditions you are setting `userY = userYTest-1; userX = userXTest-1;`. So when they go wrong the consequence is only to set the ship in the same place twice. With the first condition, when it goes wrong, it sets the ship wherever `userX` and `userY` have previously been defined, such as (0, 0).